# Orbits of a cyclic group on the powerset

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite cyclic group and denote by $\mathcal{P}(G)$ its powerset. Then $G$ acts on $\mathcal{P}(G)$ by acting on each element in a subset $S\in\mathcal{P}(G)$individually.  Is there any good description of the orbits of this action?

Comment: You should specify the action more precisely. I presume you let $g \in G$ act by right translation on each element of $S$ but there are other choices.

Comment: Ben, what exactly do you want to know? The number of orbits of each possible length?